# Как сделать ajax замену тега PHP при клике на переключатель?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть такой код, как через Ajax управлять тегами поиска при клике на переключатель?

```
<li class="uk-overflow-auto uk-overlay-default<?php if (returnPageField(return_page_slug(), 'use-header')=='on') { ?> uk-margin-large-top<?php } ?>">
    <div class="uk-padding-small">
        <h2 class="uk-text-white uk-h4 uk-margin-remove uk-padding-small uk-background-extra uk-text-center uk-border-rounded">333333 33 33333 33333?</h2>
        <div class="uk-overflow-hidden uk-margin-top uk-grid-small uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-margin-bottom" data-uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-bottom-small; target: > div; delay: 100; repeat: false;">
          <div>
            <label class="uk-border uk-padding"><input type="radio" class="uk-radio radio-<?php getPageField(return_page_slug(),'color-button'); ?>" name="branch1" value="first" /><span class="uk-margin-small-left">Мужчина</span></label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label class="uk-border uk-padding"><input type="radio" class="uk-radio radio-<?php getPageField(return_page_slug(),'color-button'); ?>" name="branch1" value="second" /><span class="uk-margin-small-left">Женщина</span></label>
          </div>                                        
        </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

php

```
<?php 
    global $language;
    get_i18n_search_results(array(
        'tags' => 'first _parent_' . return_page_slug() ,
        'lang' => @$language,
        'words' => ' ',
        'DATE_FORMAT' => '',
        'max' => 99,
        'i18n' => 0,
        'numWords' => '-1',
        'order' => '+menuOrder',
        'showPaging' => 0,
        'HEADER' => '',
        'NOT_FOUND' => ''
    )); 
?>
```

Comment: А как сам поиск происходит? Если это отдельная настройка для поиска то лучше сохранять значение в базу, при поиске брать его оттуда, а при клике перезаписывать. Ничего в php менять не надо

Comment: все это хозяйство находится в форме с методом POST, я знаю, что есть возможность манипуляций PHP переменными посредством AJAX по клику, но не знаю, как это сделать, тут происходит поиск по файлам XML, я пытаюсь ветвить свой квиз, подгружаться должны файлы с таким же тегом LI, но выбор должен идти по тегу first или second в зависимости от клика по конкретной радио кнопке